# find local network address in Android - including IP and NetMask? (ethernet not wifi)

Tags: android, networking, ip-address, mask, ethernet

In Android emulator, the address (`eth0`) is `10.0.2.15/24`

On a tablet that supports Ethernet, `eth0` has a similar address: e.g. `192.168.0.2/24`

How can I find it through existing Android APIs? (existing versions - *prior to Android L preview*!).

I know it can be done for WiFi via WifiManager.getDhcpInfo() - but I am interested in **Ethernet** - or even better a **generic** way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a method that will get the mask, AKA the network prefix length. The minimum API is 9 and the INTERNET permission is required. The address has a '/' prefix, but that can be easily removed by adding `.toString.substring(1)` or the like.

```
public void logLocalIpAddresses() {
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nwis;
    try {
        nwis = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (nwis.hasMoreElements()) {

            NetworkInterface ni = nwis.nextElement();
            for (InterfaceAddress ia : ni.getInterfaceAddresses())

                Log.i(TAG, String.format("%s: %s/%d", 
                      ni.getDisplayName(), ia.getAddress(), ia.getNetworkPrefixLength()));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I needed API 8 but I guess this will do. Cheers!

Comment: > API 9 is alright, as Ethernet starts being used in API 11 anyways!